# Div class css of parent class should not effect the children class for showing rightclick menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created context menu for several div's , in this very case the right click context menu of the child div is not displayed in expected position beacause of the class value for the parent div.

Code looks something like this :

```
<div class="col-md-{{12/list.length}}  col-right-click">
   <div>
    <h3 >Col {{$index+1}}
    </h3>
    </div>
 <!--Child div -->
 <div class="list-right-click" ng-repeat="(key,list) in item"  ng-include="'list.html'"></div>
```

The position of right click for Child div is not shown in expected `position(class="list-right-click")`, whereas it is shown properly for the parent `div(class="col-right-click")`

Answer (score 0):

If parent class is over-riding child class then use `!important` at the end of the child class style attribute. it will over-ride `any style (margin-padding-position etc)` given to the parent class.

I hope this answers your question. you did not provide complete code so this is the best answer you can get from me.But if you asking something else then let me know with a little more detail. Thanks

And if this answers your question then marked it as accepted so that this thread can be closed.

Comment: So i have to provide different style fro child div to override the parent div style?  I want the style of child div, I want the position of right click menu to be above the child div, as seen in parent div rightclick menu.

Comment: Yes, because parent style `overrides` the child style. Give child style you want but use a different class of css to style it with `!important`, we use this approach when we make our web responsive, because web has to adjust on different screen sizes. Its not a bad approach to use a different style class for a child. Its there for use, use it.

 
Parent has a css class and it is interfering with child , then give child a class and use !important to override it. I hope this answer your question.